# Get memory usage of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, runtime, profiling

I know that I Java's [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) object can report the JVM's memory usage. However, I need the memory usage for a certain thread. Any idea how to get this?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Each thread is allocated an amount of stack space. This is configurable at the JVM level. Find your JVM configuration for that and check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Thread shares everything except its stack and the CPU cycles with all other threads in the VM. All objects created by the Thread are pooled with all the other objects.

The problem is to define what the memory usage of a Thread is. Is it only those objects it created? What if these objects subsequently are referenced by other threads? Do they only count half, then? What about objects created somewhere else, but are now referenced by this Thread?

I know of no tool trying to measure the memory consumption of separate Threads.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Isn`t there sth close to that? I really have to figure out how much memory a certain thread is using. I would appreciate your reply!

Comment: Is it a unique thread, or are there others like it?  If there are others like it, then maybe you could compare the total memory usage vs. the total memory usage when running with one less thread.